# iOS live search support

Tags: ios, search

Does iOS have a built-in or a ready made library for live search similar to what is popular in the web world (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp)?

I'd like to create something like that and hook it up to Core Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to create a search bar (I believe it's UISearchBar) and put a table view below it (UITableView). Hook the "on change" event of the search bar to the `reloadData` of the table view and write some code that looks for new information in your Core Data table.

That's basically everything you need.

Comment: So i guess this means no.  I think he was looking for a library that lets you pass it a NSDictionary or Core Data and handle the logic for you.  I am looking for the same.  Just trying not to reinvent the wheel.